# Execute .vbs from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, dynamic, cmd, ssis

I have a `.vbs` script that converts a `.xlsx` to a `.csv`

I am trying to configure my `SSIS Execute Process Task` to run the `.vbs` from command prompt.  The arguments to the .vbs are dynamic so I am using SSIS expression builder to pass arguments to the task.

The command line prompt command looks like this:

```
XlsToCsv.vbs <source file.xlsx> <target file.csv>
```

I am currently configuring the Execute Process Task.

Executable: `\filePath\ExecuteXlsToCsv.bat`

.bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off
C:
cd C:\batchFilePath\
cscript
```

Arguments:

```
XlsToCsv.vbs "\sourcePath\sourceFile.xlsx" "\targetPath\targetFile.csv"
```

Whenever I execute, it's successful, but I don't see my new files as planned.  How can I see what the command is doing upon execution?

Comment: cscript.exe is what runs console mode VB scripts, try that.

Comment: And don't use pictures for trivial output you could easily copy and paste from a cmd window.

Comment: Why use a script for something that is an OOTB functionality of SSIS? You can create an Excel source and link it to a Flat file destination. Are you trying to load the Excel data to the database? Then you don't need to convert anything. Just use an Excel source

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am worried about the performance...In the past, Excel to SQL loads have been much slower than csv.

Comment: And the conversion will be faster ? How *are* you converting the data anyway? Opening a file with Excel and saving it to a csv is slow and error-prone. You'll have to install Excel on the server and will probably end up with orphaned processes.

Comment: True...but at this point I am just curious as to how to dynamicize a .bat execution from SSIS